# Getting theta of Line Equation

Tags: trigonometry, pi

Please forgive my lack of knowledge, which i think it's one of those basic formula related to Trigonometry.

Let's look at visual example:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwoMn9VKDw-tSVNRMm9RWGp3dTg/view?usp=sharing

I have 5 lines, with their line equation (let's say they have zero offset ok)
how can i calculate the Theta of each line equation make (in Pi)? (i would appreciate if you explain in detail so i understand the concept)

also I have seen this:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwoMn9VKDw-tZndRMW41Qnc1aUk/view?usp=sharing

Are they generated from Theta of line equations? or it's another theory which help to find the theta?
much appreciate your time and effort

Comment: What  do you mean by  theta of a line ?  Is it the angle between the st line and the x axis ??

Comment: @Nizar yeah the angle of each Equation make, i thought it's called Theta, no?

Comment: By the way, welcome to MSE, some quick notes:  1. This site uses [Mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-qu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bick-reference) to type questions.   2. Please have a look on  ["How to ask a good Question"](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Nizar thanks, i actually join just today, hehehe... also i'm not good in math, but i'm trying to catch up.

Comment: If you are dealing with st lines having thier equations, then the tangent of the angle between the st. line and the horisental x axis is equal to the slope of the st. Line , i.e. $\tan(\theta)= slope$ , are you familiar with the expression "slope" ?

Comment: @Nizar not really, i guess i need to read about that. i understand Algebra i can say i'm quite okay on that, and just started study on trigonometric.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34370/discussion-between-bernardrouhi-and-nizar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We wish to find the angle between each line (passing through the origin) and the horizontal axis, given the equations of the lines.

Notice that for a given line through the origin, the slope is $m = \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}.$ As such, this is identical to the definition of tangent, which states $\tan(\theta) = \frac{\text{opp}}{\text{adj}}.$ We can now write that $\tan(\theta) = m.$ Given the value of $m,$ we can find $\theta$ with the relation $\boxed{\theta = \arctan(m)}.$